# make an exponential curve tend to a specific value

Tags: exponential-function, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to make the following curve to exhibit an exponential decline from a given value to zero. So far, I only managed to make it go from infinite to zero.. Thus I still need to make the curve smoothly increase for smaller values, up to a preset value "top"

Here is the expression in R language:

```
cu=function(t){
  -(c-t)*I/(a-t)*(1+exp((b-t)*I))
}
top=2000 # maximum value for the curve
a=35 # minimum value, at which the curve should take value "top"
b=42 # value to create an inflexion point
c=45 # value to make curve zero 
I=3.4 # parameter to make the decrease in values faster

s=curve(cu,from=a,to=c,n=20)
plot(s)
```

Thanks in advance!

addendum: as suggested, I edited the curve to:

```
 cu=function(t){(-(c-a)*I/(a-t+g))*(1+exp((b-t)*I))}
```

but then, when using the parameters

```
 top=2000# 
 a=35# 
 b=42.5# 
 c=45#   
 I=3.4 #
```

estimating parameter g from top

```
g=long/(-(c−a)*I*(1+(exp((b−a)*I))))
```

plotting the curve

```
 curve(cu,from=a,to=c,col="blue",n=10,
  ylim=c(0,long+100),
  xlim=c(34,50))
```

It does not stop at 2000

Comment: Do you have to you use the specific functional form or would you be amenable to modifying it? if $a$ is your lower bound, then modifying the denominator to something like $(a-t+g)$ such that $\frac{-(c-a)I}{g}(1+e^{(b-a)I})$ equals your "top value" at $t=a$ would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you introduce a paraneter $g$ into the modified functional form

$$f(t)=\frac{-(c-a)I}{a-t+g}(1+e^{(b-t)I})$$

then estimating $g$ as

$$g=\frac{-(c-a)I(1+e^{(b-a)I})}{2000}$$

gives you $g=-368686801.482604$ for your specified values of $a$,$b$,$c$ and $I$.

Your curve then looks like

[image]

and you see the inflexion point at $b=42$ only when it's plotted on a log-scale, because your decay rate is rather large. I tried playing around with a multiplier on the argument of the exponential as well as varying $I$, but it didn't do much.

[image]

For a different set of parameters, the curve looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks heaps!

Comment: More than welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: umm, but it does not seem to work  when i change the values for other parameters. I need that it always gives f(t)=top when t=a. I might be doing something wrong here, though. Please, see my edits in the question.

Comment: I changed $a$, $b$,$c$ and $I$ and still got $f(a)=2000$. Did you recalculate $g$ when you changed the values of the other parameters?

Comment: I added a graph to my answer showing a case for $a=35,c=45,b=42.5$ and $I=3.4$ For this case, $g=−2.018E+9$

Comment: A THOUSAND APOLOGIES!!!!! I had the formula for $g$ upside down in my original answer!! Please let me know if this fix works for you as well!. Sorry again!

Comment: Your formula for g in R-code should have a 2000 in the denominator . I think that  if you change it to g=-(c−a)*I*(1+(exp((b−a)*I)))/2000 it should work.

Comment: thank you! that made sense. However, i now its like I lost the ability to change the rate of decrease, using parameter I, wonder if that is solvable. It is important because later i need to adjust that curve to a set of points.

Comment: This is a consequence of constraining the range of variation within a fairly narrow $(a,c)$ band. Would you be willing to eliminate the hard constraint $f(c)=0$ and let $f(t)$ asymptotically approach 0, as $t\rightarrow c$? This may open up some options.

Comment: That seems a very clever alternative, thanks!

Comment: Dear Sharat, I found that the inflexion point actualy changes the behavior of the curve in the opposite way it should, would it be possible to make that the decay rate increases at values over b (i.e. the curve becomes concave?).

Comment: Hello Avis, I just saw this. Please give me a few hours to refamiliarise myself with the minutiae of the problem and I’ll revert. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Sharat, pleas take the time you need. A final problem i got is that i was unable to now optimize two unknown parameters, I and g, to make the curve passing through known values of y for given values of x. I can make of that a different question, if you think it is more convenient.